# Do I have to create a class to handle application-level events?

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/using-events-with-the-application-object) about
"Using events with the Application object" states:

> Before you can use events with the **Application** object, you must create a class module and declare an object of type **Application** with events.

In my workbook in `ThisWorkbook`s module I have the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents App As Excel.Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_SomeEvent()
    'This event fires without problems
End Sub
```

There is no problem with the code, as far as I have tested. However the above mentioned article made me think:

I know `ThisWorkbook` is a class module, same as sheet modules, but can I actually use them for this purpose?
Is there anything I have to keep in mind when not creating a new class module, or is the article wrong in that I *have* to create a class module?

Comment: You don't have to create a new class module. It just means that that code should be in a class, which it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is absolutely possible to let ThisWorkbook module handle Application events.

What you need to keep in mind, if ever, is it violates [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Handling Application events is not the responsibility of a Workbook. Creating a dedicated class to handle Application events for specific purpose may help to keep the architecture clean.

However, from the stand point of the feature itself, there is no problem.